# How to get the history callback metrics in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

How can I retrieve the history of callback metrics? I have a class `Metrics` and I use it in the `fit` function of Keras model as follows `callbacks=[model_metrics]`.

This is the complete code of the class `Metrics` and `fit` function.

```
class Metrics(Callback):

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_bal_accs = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        val_predict = np.argmax((np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))).round(), axis=1)
        val_targ = np.argmax(self.validation_data[1], axis=1)
        _val_f1 = metrics.f1_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
        _val_bal_acc = metrics.balanced_accuracy_score(val_targ, val_predict)    
        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
        self.val_bal_accs.append(_val_bal_acc)
        print(" — val_f1: {:f} — val_bal_acc: {:f}".format(_val_f1, _val_bal_acc))
        return

model_metrics = Metrics()

history = model.fit(np.array(X_train), y_train, 
                    validation_data=(np.array(X_test), y_test),
                    epochs=5,
                    batch_size=2,
                    callbacks=[model_metrics],
                    shuffle=False,
                    verbose=1)
```

How can I get the `history` of `val_f1` and `val_bal_acc`? Now I can only access `loss`, `val_loss`, `acc`, `val_acc`:

```
print(history.history.keys())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To interact with `keras` history API you need to pass in arguments for `metrics` and not `callbacks`.

In it's current state your `val_f1` and `val_bal_acc` aren't going to be stored in the history object but will rather be stored in your `model_metrics` object.

You can access them like so:

```
model_metrics.val_f1s
```

It's the same as accessing an attribute for any object.

Finally if you do want to create a custom metric and want access it from history you need to define a custom metric (as a function) and then pass it into the `metrics` kwarg in `model.compile`. This is done like so:

```
def my_metric(y_true y_pred):
    return y_true # just a dummy return value

# assume that the model is defined somewhere
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=..., metrics = [my_metric]
```

And then you will be able to find `val_my_metric` in the history object that you get out of the fit.

Comment: Should it be `my_metric(y_pred, y_true)` or `my_metric(y_true, y_pred)` or it does not really matter?

Comment: Also, I tried to create a function as follows: `def my_metric(targ, predict):
    val_targ = np.argmax(targ, axis=1)
    return metrics.balanced_accuracy_score(val_targ, predict)`, but it fails with the following message:  `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'argmax'`.

Comment: For your second comment I think you should use tf.argmax or tf.math.argmax